# API Integration with website

Tags: php, html, json

i have been assigned to integrate an API in a blog.

API URL:http://www.ask-oracle.com/charts/api.php?dt=2015-10-19T08%3A48%3A32%2B05%3A30

I am able to get the data using

```
$data = file_get_contents('http://www.ask-oracle.com/charts/api.php?dt=' .$date .'T08%3A48%3A32%2B05%3A30');
```

But not able to organize it properly.

It returned JSON array, i need your help in getting out the data and show properly(organized way) in my blog.
Please help me, how i can do it.
I will be very thankful to you if you provide me code(in html or php) also.

Comment: use `json_decode` to get a regular php object / array. Then iterate it to format however you require. As it stands this question is far too vague to answer

Comment: You've been assigned a very basic programming task. I can understand the confusion on how to use some functions, but your question seems to require that we produce the code for you. I suggest you narrow your needs better.

Answer (score 0):

This is up to you to decide how to organize this. As @steve suggested it, you should convert the JSON stream to a PHP object, and then transform it to HTML to "organize" it for humans who are not able to read JSON. It will surely also involve CSS.

If somebody asked you this work but didn't gave more informations about how to display it and you have no idea about how to do it, you should maybe ask for more precise specifications before starting the work.

Note that saying that JSON is not *properly organized* is not exact. JSON **is** a structured data notation.